# Display Calculated column in List NewForm

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, jquery

How to display Calculated column in SharePoint List NewForm.aspx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need javascript. We just add xml display like DispForm.aspx like below.

`<xsl:value-of select="@Calculated_Column_Name" />`

Here is the link for detail explanation [add-calculated-field-in-editformaspx-in-sharepoint-2013](http://menetes.blogspot.co.id/2016/03/add-calculated-field-in-editformaspx-in.html)

Comment: Your link goes to a blank page.

Answer (score 2):

Calculated columns are rendered when the item is created and edited. To show it on a NewForm, you'll have to create your own javascript to display it based on what the rules are defined in the column definition.